# How to fix the gap between footer and end of html body?

Tags: html, css

I added a footer to my page but for some reason there is a gap between the footer and the ending of the body. I am not sure how to fix this issue. I have made many webpages without this issue.

I have included the HTML and CSS from what I have created. I cannot find any issue with the code I have.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0 0 var(--header-height) 0;
}

section {
    margin-top: 3rem;
}

.coloredSection {
    background-color: var(--pale-green);
    color: white;
}
.container {
    margin-left: 1.5rem;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<footer id="contact" class="coloredSection contact">
          <div class="row align-items-center projects container">
          <div>
            <h1>Contact Me</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="contactLinks" id="contacts">
            <a
              id="profile-link"
              href="https://github.com/"
              target="_blank"
              class="btn contactDetails"><i class="fab fa-github"></i> GitHub</a>
            <a
              href="https://twitter.com/"
              target="_blank"
              class="btn contactDetails"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
            <a
              href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/"
              target="_blank"
              class="btn contactDetails"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i> LinkedIn</a>
            <a href="mailto:" 
              class="btn contactDetails"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Email me</a>
          </div>
          <div class="attribution">
            ©2022 | Designed and Coded by Kianna Hendricks
          </div>
        </div>
</footer>
      <!-- End Contact -->
</body>
</html>
```

Image:
[image: screenshot of footer of webpage and gap between footer and end of body]

Comment: The `html` and `css` provided in the question is not proper. Not able to replicate issue. Can you please update the question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have set a margin-bottom for the body:

**var(--header-height)**

```
body {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0 0 var(--header-height) 0; 
}
```

Change margin to `margin:0;` and it will work fine.

Comment: I changed the margin to 0 but the gap is still there.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. I accidently added the projects class to the contact row div. After removing it, the gap went away.